# Align custom text to extreme right and center

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, navbar

In my ASP.NET MVC5 application, I wanted display custom text `Hello User!!` to extreme right and vertically align it to center. To achieve this, I implemented `nav navbar-nav navbar-right`. The text is in extreme right but its vertical alignment is still on top. How do I set its vertical alignment to center?

Below is the code from my _Layout.cshtml file.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li style="color:white">Hello User !!</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Nav bar alignment issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2s3O.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the class `navbar-text` to display text.

You can replace

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li style="color:white">Hello User !!</li>
</ul>
```

By

```
<p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Hello User</p>
```

Take a look at the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-text)

Comment: Thanks a ton Kevin. This solved my problem and I am now able to align text at right corner and vertically in center.

Answer (score 0):

increase the line-height in css it should be greater than height.

Comment: Thanks Varun.

<li style="color: white; line-height: 50px;">Hello User !!</li>